# Install SSL Certificate on EC2 Windows Instance

Tags: iis, aws, ssl, ec2

tengo una instancia de EC2 Windows en AWS. Necesito instalar un certificado SSL en uno de mis dominios. Hice todos los pasos para crear y completar el certificado en IIS, pero luego de completar la instalación "desaparece". Intente ejecutar el comando `certutil -repairstore my Serial_number` pero me pregunta por una "Smart Card". Intente deshabilitarla de la manera que explica el siguiente link, pero nada. Alguna idea?

Para variar el soporte de AWS no contesta en mas de 24 horas.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9773/2238/ssl-disappears-from-the-certificate-list-on-windows-server

Answer (score 0):

Para un certificado-SSL en Windows (en EC2-AWS), te recomiendo usar el sistema automatizado "Certbot" (compatible con Apache, Nginx y otros).

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/windows-other

Después de completar la instalación, puedes configurar más parámetros, en el caso que tengas un certificado-SSL personalizado.